# Custom google map for Webview Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-webview

I am developing an Android restaurant app completely web-based. I am trying to add the address of the restaurant so that when you click on it the map opens within the application. I have tried to create my own custom google map and add locations and then reference the link text by simple `<a href=http://www.google.com/mapmaker?gw=39...>` tag.

However, this open the entire google page. How can i do away with search bar and rest of the content and just show the map. Thanks

Comment: add the code you have tried so far